# How are vertex shader outs sent as inputs to the fragment shader?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

I'm learning some OpenGL 3.2 way of doing things and I think it's quite great, I'm actually understanding more of shaders and non-fixed pipeline in 1 week rather than those 2 years I tried to learn OpenGL fixed pipeline functions. But here's my question:

From what I think I've understood the vertex shader is run for each vertexes in the VBO. But the fragments shader is run per each pixel (is that right?) which is a huge number compared to let's say 3 vertexes of a triangle.

Now it seems that in the vertex shader the out variables (like colors and stuff) are passed 1 to 1 to the fragment shader. But let's say that I pass to the fragment shader the position of the vertex in the vertex shader. How is all executed? What vertex (A, B or C of the hipothetical triangle) is passed per each fragment and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because we're working with triangles all the information the vertex shader has can be interpolated along the surface of the triangle. A useful way of doing this is by using [Barycentric coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinates_%28mathematics%29).

OpenGL does this interpolation for us automatically, for example consider the following vertex shader:

```
#version 130

attribute vec4 position;        // vertex position from VBO
attribute vec2 uv;              // texture coordinates from VBO 

uniform vec3 camera;            // position of the camera   
uniform mat4 projection;        // camera projection matrix

smooth out vec2 texel;          // smoothed texture coordinate for fragment shader

void main()
{   

    gl_Position = projection * (position - vec4(camera.x, camera.y, camera.z, 0.0));
    texel = uv;
}
```

This is an extremely standard vertex shader. The vertex has a position which is transformed using the camera and projection matrices.

As you can see from the comment we also output a 'smoothed texture coordinate for the fragment shader'. Using the OpenGL keyword `smooth` we tell OpenGL to interpolate this variable over the surface of the triangle of which this is one vertex. Conversely there is also the `flat` keyword which doesn't do this.

Now in the frament shader we consume this data:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D diffuse;      // diffuse texture
smooth in vec2 texel;           // where we should sample the texture

out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
    outputColor = texture(diffuse, texel);
}
```

Et voila, we have our nicely textured triangle instead of just a triangle made up of the three colours made from whatever `sample(texture,uv)` would've been in each vertex.

**Edit** the following quote is directly take from the file `teodron` [linked](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/provoking_vertex.txt). I thought it would be a good idea to add this to the answer to make it more complete and hopefully answer Jeffrey's question in the comments.

> The provoking vertex of a primitive is the vertex that determines the
>   constant primary and secondary colors when flat shading is enabled.
>
> In OpenGL, the provoking vertex for triangle, quad, line, and
>   (trivially) point primitives is the last vertex used to assemble the
>   primitive.  The polygon primitive is an exception in OpenGL where the
>   first vertex of a polygon primitive determines the color of the
>   polygon, even if actually broken into triangles and/or quads.

Comment: Let's assume I do `out vec3 VPosition; int main() { ... VPosition = position; }` in the vertex shader. What would the value `in vec4 VPosition;` in the fragments shader for all of those fragments?

Comment: The uninterpolated value so position

Comment: Of which vertex? A, B or C?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/provoking_vertex.txt Related to your "which vertex" question..